# How to use sap.ui.commons.layout:MatrixLayout inside a sap.m Page in UI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How to use sap.ui.commons.layout:MatrixLayout inside a sap.m Page? What should be the aggregation?

Comment: you need to put some `MatrixLayoutRow` in it, and then in the Rows some `MatrixLayoutCell`and in the Cells you can put any control as you like. But consider the `MatrixLayout` is deprecated since 1.38 and you should use `sap.ui.layout.Grid` instead

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn´t do that at all, because the combination of sap.m and sap.ui.commons is not supported.

[Supported Library Combinations](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/363cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820.html)

If your really want nevertheless it to do, the solution is the same as binding e.g. sap.tnt components. But you will get rendering issues.

---

Edit: But to answer your question here the example: [Bad Matrix Layout example](http://jsbin.com/befacoq/edit?html,output)